# iframe rendered by jsp within php site

Tags: php, jsp, session, iframe, state

I have a php site and a iframe which is rendering content from jsp site.
Can that iframe(link to jsp) after loading the content allow form submission, state management etc within the iframe?
What could be issues in handling these stuff in php site when content is rendered through jsp links? 
can I still maintain the state? php form and form through jsp will have their conversational states, how can these be managed?

Thanks

Comment: Each will just have their own independent session which are in no way correlated with each other if they're served from different domains/contexts. I'm not sure if I understand your *concrete* problem. What exactly is the problem you're having with it? What exactly is the functional requirement? Stack Overflow is about concrete problems/questions, not about vague assumptions or doubts.

Comment: Why didn't you write all this in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346287/jsp-iframe-in-php-site) ?

Comment: There are two forms, one on the main site and one under iframe. I need to retrieve info from both the forms (after submission) and render the dropdown within  iframe. Now I am assessing if it is possible or not, vice versa? Going forward will there be any challenges while using JS on both the sites etc?